# Creating additional Primary partition without wiping entire HDD

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

The current state of partitions on my 500gb HDD is as follows:
[image]

I'm not really good when it comes to partitioning. I probably did something foolish to end up here. 
But the problem is I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm unable to create multiple partitions as once I create `/boot` partition remaining space becomes `unusable`.
During Ubuntu installation it shows as:

```
/dev/sda
   /dev/sda1    350mb
   /dev/sda2    155gb
   /dev/sda3    156gb
   /dev/sda4    153gb
```

Is it possible to create additional primary partition (preferably without having to wipe off everything?

Is it possible to create `/dev/sdb`?

Comment: I don't know if you have a reason for separating D and E, but like noggerl said, I would using gparted to delete E, delete/resize D to your preference, create an extended partition in the newly freed space, and then create as many logical partitions as you need inside the extended partition (root, swap, etc). **Make sure you select "Something Else..." at the Ubuntu installer so you can inform it of your custom setup.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [gparted livecd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) you can resize your partitions as you want. But be aware to save your data because manipulating your partition table can always lead to data loss.

`/dev/sdb` refers to an other harddrive. So `/dev/sda` is the first harddrive, `sdb` the second, `sdc` the third and so on. USB-Sticks also will be named in this order if you plug them in.

I have reread the question for a third time and have another clarification for your primary partition question: it is not possible to make a fifth primary partition because there is a partition table limit of four. What you can do is make the last of the primary partitions to extended partition table and create up to 7 logical volumes in that.

Comment: I can use gparted from within the Ubutntu 13.10 live disk. Both D: and E: drives don't contain anything important. Ideally I wanted to make a 20GB partition out of D: and use it to install Ubuntu.

Comment: It's better to make changes in partitions when the drive is not mounted, hence the recommendation of gparted live cd.

Comment: If all your partitions contain data, you can convert from primary to logical using [FixParts;](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts) however, there are some caveats -- see the FixParts page for details. If any of your partitions is empty, you can delete it and create an extended partition in its place; the extended partition can then hold as many logical partitions as you like.